# VSCode doesn't show docstring for pandas module and some functions like read_csv

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

VSCode doesn't show the docstring for the import pandas. This is show for other libraries like Numpy and Scipy. Also is doesn't show the docstring for read_csv, but for read_excel is show. The variable and type are shown.

I think might be an issue with pylance stubs. Tried restarting the LSP, but it did not help. Not sure if it is a bug or a normal issue. Also it happen with a completely different python installation using a remote env. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Not displaying Pandas docstring also occurs in my VSCode. It only displays `(module)pandas`, but `read_csv` can still be displayed normally. I've submit [the issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/4881) to developer in github.

Comment: Thanks for sharing issue ticket. So there is not a unique case. Still no idea why read_csv behavior is different. Weird. Let's see if there is some news from the issue.